# Mount an NFS share as non root user in cli

Tags: nfs

My `/etc/exports`

```
/root/backup       192.168.30.26(rw,sync,insecure,all_squash,no_subtree_check)
```

While I mounting as non root user,

```
mount -o v3 192.168.30.26:/root/backup /usr/backup/
```

I got `mount: only root can do that`

Note: I saw option `user` in fstab. Is there anyway without it ?

Comment: Yes, only `root` could specifiy options to mount command, you have to run `mount` with only target from fstab as argument: `mount /usr/backup`.

Answer (score 7):

Users could modify system's mount table either by

- using `sudo` or `su`

**or** by

- having one entrie with `user,noauto` options, in /etc/fstab

### Sample:

- #### server side

  If on *server host* whith IP address **`192.168.30.11`**, you have in `/etc/exports`

  ```
  /srv/share 192.168.30.26(rw,sync,insecure,all_squash,no_subtree_check)
  ```
- #### client side

  On client host, with IP address **`192.168.30.26`** you have to add in `/etc/fstab` something like:

  ```
  192.168.30.11:/srv/share   /usr/backup    nfs    rw,relatime,user,noauto   0   0
  ```

Then, ***users*** on 192.168.30.26 must be able to mount share by just running:

```
mount /usr/backup
```

without `sudo`.

- `noauto` prevent system to mount the share at boot time.
- `user` tell system to autorize *(local) users* to mount the share.

Comment: > Note: I saw option user in fstab. Is there anyway without it ?

Comment: Thanks. But as i mentioned above i already saw user option i fstab.

Comment: @RajagopalSubramanian Ok, then my answer is *user must be able to `mount /path/to/target`*. If this is not case, please post answer and/or last lines of `dmesg` command.

Comment: @Hanginoninquietdesperation Users could *modify* system mount table either by using `sudo` or `su` or by having entry with `user,noauto` in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I have one more doubt. As non-root user Can I mount  on  any folder ? For ex, Now I can only mount over /usr/backup. How to overcome this ?

Comment: @RajagopalSubramanian No **`only root can do that`**, as *user* you could only run `mount` with 1 argument: the target. And this **must** be configured (by root user) in `/etc/fstab`

Answer (score 4):

Adapted from [How to mount NFS share as a regular user - by Dan Nanni](https://web.archive.org/web/20180318145719/http://www.xmodulo.com/how-to-mount-nfs-share-as-regular-user.html):

> In order to allow a regular user to mount NFS share, you can do the following.

> On the NFS client host (e.g., 10.1.1.20), update /etc/fstab as root.
>
> ```
> $ sudo vi /etc/fstab
>
> 192.168.30.26:/root/backup /usr/backup nfs rw,noauto,user 0 0
>                                                      ^^^^
> ```
>
> In the above, **"user"** allows a non-root user to mount, and "noauto" means no automatic mount on boot.

> On the NFS server host (e.g., 10.1.1.10), enable export for the client as root.
>
> If you want to enable export non-permanently (which is not persistent across reboots):
>
> ```
>  $ sudo exportfs 192.168.30.26:/export -o rw,async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check
> ```

> If you want to enable export permanently (which is persistent across reboots):
>
> ```
>  $ sudo vi /etc/exports
>
>  /export 192.168.30.26(rw,async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)
>
>  $ sudo exportfs -a
> ```
>
> Now you can log in as "user" on the NFS client host, and do NFS mount as follows.
>
> ```
>  $ mount /usr/backup
> ```

Comment: Downvoted for plagiarising without any attribution to original author: http://xmodulo.com/how-to-mount-nfs-share-as-regular-user.html

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan no longer available.

Comment: Thanks, @Neurotransmitter I've edited the answer to provide attribution for the plargiarised content with link to archived version of the original article.

Comment: Nice one, thanks, in the meantime I've downvoted this answer to discourage the author from keep doing this.

Answer (score 3):

That why people have invented **automounter**. On a RPM based system:

**as root**

```
$ yum install autofs
$ systemctl enable --now autofs
```

**as regular user**

```
$ cd /net/<hostname>
```

where **hostname** is the name of the server.

Note: there is no need for en explicit mount. The autofs daemon will mount transparently as soon as user changes into that directory.

Comment: I'm surprised but this actually works (well, until I have permissions problems with the actual dir).

Answer (score 1):

You can use sudo

```
sudo mount -o v3 192.168.30.26:/root/backup /usr/backup/
```

You would need to add something suitable to the sudoers file e.g.

```
test ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/mount -o v3 192.168.30.26:/root/backup /usr/backup/
```

which would allow the user test to execute the exact command listed without providing a password. You should take a look at the [sudo](https://www.sudo.ws/man/sudo.man.html) and [sudoers](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.19/sudoers.man.html)  documentation.

Comment: I actually want to mount it inside container.  can I use tis inside docker container ?  Bcz I have user called `cinder` inside the container.  But `cinder` user is not live outside the container.

Comment: After updating /etc/sudoers file, When I switch to another user I got     `>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 32 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 32                                              sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but have you checked the permissions of /usr/backup/ ?

Most likely, your non-root user does nor have permissions to the /usr/backup folder.

Most likely they are similar to the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Aug 15 21:51 backup
```

Try adding a group with your user in it to that folder's permissions.